# AdvancedDataGridView - set custom filter programmatically

Tags: filtering, advanceddatagrid

I use the AdvancedDataGridView (https://github.com/davidegironi/advanceddatagridview) connected on a Datasource.  The user is able to create custom filter without any problem.  What I try to do is to define the same custom filter but programmatically.  I would like to be able to create a custom filter on a column and that this custom filter definition appear as normally if it would be created manually so the user can acces it by the filtering icon and activate/deactivate it.  I can't success to do that...  :-(

I don't want to use the "LoadFilterAndSort" sub because it locks all additionnal filtering/sorting the user could want to add.

Is there a way to get this?

I thank you.

Steph.